# Spring-security not working, need help understanding why

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to understand Spring-security but my pages can be accessed without loggin in and I don't understand why.

The "secure" page is located in WEB-INF/pages/secure and is accessed using `http://localhost:8080/secret`. This *should* not allow access, but currently does.

/secure maps here

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorld {

    ...

    @RequestMapping("/secret")
    public String showSecret(ModelMap model) {
        return "secure/secretPage";
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
...
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/springmvc-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
...
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
    login-page="/login"
    authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/secure/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAccountDetailsService"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

userAccountDetailsService

```
@Service("userAccountDetailsService") // enables component to be found to <component-scan/>
public class UserAccountDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
    }

}
```

The /login page does not currently exist. There are no users anyway. I just want this to disallow access for now.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are hitting is `/secure`, not `/pages/secure` and yet in your Spring Security configuration you are protecting `/pages/secure/**` instead of `/secure/**`.  Change the intercept URL from `/pages/secure/**` to `/secure/**` and try again.

Comment: Didn't work for some reason. But then, secure is placed in /pages/secure. I tried moving it to /WEB-INF/secure (samelevel as /WEB-INF/pages), but for some reason pages/ is treated as root: HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/pages/secure/secretPage.jsp

Comment: I copied your code with slight simplifications to a sample app and it works fine.  [Access the app](http://spring-security-starter.appspot.com/) and click the link shown on the page.  You will be redirected to the login page (as expected).  The full source code is available [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-starter).  You seem to have an error somewhere else in your configuration.  If you are still facing the error, post the complete Spring MVC and Spring Security configuration along with a screenshot of your full folder structure (not just inside WEB-INF).

Comment: I have no idea what the problem was, but it was "resolved" by deleting and rewriting all config files.